# Mongodb C# query nested document

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I use mongodb with c# driver.I have a collection which contains subdocument

```
public class EntityA 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<EntityB> BItems { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public string BName { get; set; }

    public string BDesc { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create query and take list of `EntityB` items

```
from a in mycollection
where BItems.Any(k => k.BName == entity.Name)
select a.BItems;
```

I can query nested document but when I retrive the list all other child items come to list how can I take list of BItems to meet up my criteria.I can query subdocument but when I want to take list All Bitems are coming to mylist

Comment: I'd suggest to update post along with sample MongoDB documents and desired document you want to see in response to your query.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood you correctly you want to return `BItems` collections when `BName` is equals to it's parents `Name` field? If that is the case than it goes like this:

```
var result = from a in mycollection
             from b in a.BItems
             where a.Name == b.BName
             select b;
```

Comment: @NikolaLukovic, you have a little error in your query. You should project using `b` instead of  `a.BItems`

Comment: I upgrade my driver to latest version but I still get The SelectMany query operator is not supported error

Comment: $project or $group does not support {document} when I want to execute query

Answer (score 1):

AS I Understand SelectMany meets to unwind propert in mongodb and to use unwind property we cannot add criteria directly.

[MongoDB finding nested objects that meet criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499362/mongodb-finding-nested-objects-that-meet-criteria)

```
       var result = from k in (from a in col.AsQueryable()
                     from b in a.Columns        
                     select b) where k.ColumnName==a.Name select k;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I tested with MongoDB C# driver 2.2.3 and MongoDB 3.2.1 and indeed [SelectMany](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.2/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_MongoQueryable_SelectMany__3.htm) is already supported, so you can also do this:

```
 var entities= mycollection.AsQueryable<EntityA>()
                           .SelectMany(e=>e.BItems, (e,b)=>new {entityA=e,bitem=b})
                           .Where(t => t.entityA.Name == t.bitem.Name)
                           .Select(t=>t.bitem)
                           .ToList();
```

### Update

Another possible solution could be fetching first the data and filtering latter in memory:

```
var entities= mycollection.AsQueryable<EntityA>()
                          .Select(e=>new{e.Name,e.BItems}).ToList();

var result=entities.SelectMany(e=>e.BItems.Where(b=>b.Name==e.Name));
```

Comment: I upgrade my driver to latest version but I still get The SelectMany query operator is not supported error

Comment: What version of MongoDB do you have installed?

Comment: Maybe is only supported to MongoDB 3.X server version. Did you try with my second solution?

Comment: I have to many record,if I try to filter in memory that time i have performance issue

Comment: My DB version is 3.07

Comment: Well in that case, i don't know how my test worked. I think to achieve what you need on server side, you will need to use the aggregation framework

Comment: Here is my code sample;I have nested document in my DGTable collection. MongoDatabase database;
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://myconnection");
var server = client.GetServer();
database = server.GetDatabase("MyDB");
MongoCollection<DGTable> collection;
collection = database
    .GetCollection<DGTable>(typeof(DGTable).Name);

var result = collection.AsQueryable()
    .SelectMany(p => p.TableColumns);
var abc = result.ToList();

Comment: I find the problem ,I change my repository code I have some obsole methods and select many works now.But when I want to add criteria this time I get $project or $group does not support {document} error

Comment: Could you update your question with your new code to see what are you trying yo achieve?